# What grunt files to upload to repo vs files to upload when deploying site to production

Tags: deployment, gruntjs, repository, yeoman, bower

So, I have a webapp I am creating using the 3 muskateers yeoman, grunt and bower.

My questions are:

- What is best practice when it comes to uploading my webapp into a git/mercurial repo? Do I include the entire project? What about directories like 'node_modules' or 'test', etc?
- Also, when deploying to live production site: Will my 'dist' folder be what I should be uploading?

With research yielding no results (I could be searching the wrong things?).. I'm a bit new to this process so any feedback is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always commit all of your yeoman, grunt, and bower config files.

There are two schools of thought on committing the output they produce or dependencies they download:

One is, you should upload everything needed for another user to deploy the web app after cloning the repository, without performing any additional operations. The idea is, dependencies may not exist anymore, network connections might be down, etc.

Another is, keep the repository small and don't commit node_modules, etc, since they can be downloaded by the user.

As far as the dist folder goes, yes you'll be uploading it to your server, as it contains all of your minified files. Whether or not you want to commit it to the repository is a separate question. You might let the user build every time, assuming they can get all the dependencies one way or another (from above choice). Or you might want to commit it to tag it with a release version along with your source code.

There's some more discussion on this here: http://addyosmani.com/blog/checking-in-front-end-dependencies/